# Destructor not being called as expected

Tags: c++, unix, c++11

I'm writing a server application. Following RIIA, in the constructor of one of my classes I create a file and in the destructor I delete it. This class is wrapped in a unique_ptr. This being a server application, I can only kill it by sending it a signal (SIGINT).

The strange part is that I've placed std::cerr statements on the destructors of the class held by the unique_ptr and they're not called when the application closes/dies.

Is this expected when ctrl+c is pressed or am I missing something obvious in relation to destructors?

Comment: RIIA -> RAII (Resource Acquisition Is Initialization)

Comment: What do you think the control flow of your program is when you press Ctrl-C?

Comment: @BryanChen - This is a normal class called from an instance of ServerApplication of the POCO framework. Not much code at all, actually.

Comment: @KerrekSB - I don't know. I guess the operating system sends a signal to the process and kills it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signal processing and C++ exceptions are distinct features. Signals (chiefly a *nix feature) are caught by signal handlers; I believe that although in a sense certainly the "scope" changes, it is changed from outside the C++ run time and thus does not trigger the usual stack unwinding (it's like moving in a second dimension with respect to the stack, so to speak). Googling pointed me to this post which I found interesting: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2011-08/msg00253.html.

Comment: Sending the signal does indeed raise an exception. I guess I need to catch the signal and clean up when that happens.

Comment: Yes, you need to have the daemon exit gracefully, not just abort.